# Bluetooth usb device not detected on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ibeacon, raspbian, bluez

I recently bought a Radius Network Beacon Developer Kit, and I installed the pibeacon image provided by the radius network on to Rapberry Pi Model B. i am using USB powered beacon provided by the Radius Network. Bluez (5.31) is already pre-installed in the Raspbian os image.
When I do a **lsusb** I get the output as:
*Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.*
*Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub*
*Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.*
*Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter*
*Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2458:0001*

When I try the commands **hcitool dev**:
*Devices:*
When I try the command **hcitool lesscan**:
*Device is not available: No such device

**hciconfig** also gives a blank output*
But when I try **hcitool lesscan --duplicates** I get the following output:
*[1]+ 6044*

The command **beacon scan** and **beacon stop** returns
*Send failed: File descriptor in bad state.*
And
*Invalid device : Network is down*

I even tried turning on the hci0 , but nothing seems to be working. Please help.

Comment: Has this ever worked?  It sounds like the Bluetooth dongle is not in a functional state.  This can happen sometimes, but is normally resolved by power cycling the Pi or unplugging the bluetooth dongle and plugging it back in.

Comment: To clarify, what do you have plugged in to the Raspberry Pi?  Is it a RadBeacon USB or is it the GBU521 bluetooth dongle sold with the development kit?

Comment: Yes it is the RadBeacon USB,  I think this mught be the issue, I do not have other bluetooth dongle. I have ordered it today. I will check with GBU521.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Radius Networks Pi Beacon (also known as the Beacon Development Kit) is a Raspberry Pi that ships with an IOGear GBU521 Bluetooth LE dongle and an SD card with software to make it transmit an iBeacon signal.  This software uses the Linux BlueZ framework to transmit, which requires a standard Bluetooth 4.x device.

Based on the comments below the question, it is clear that the problem is attempting to use the software and Raspberry Pi to control a RadBeacon USB dongle.  This won't work, because a RadBeacon USB is a standalone beacon device, and not a general purpose Bluetooth 4.x device.  The solution is to use a standard Bluetooth 4.x device like the recommended GBU521.